# cascade delete doesn't work even though constraint is added

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE message_link
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  thread_id integer,
  message_id integer,
  user_id integer,
  read boolean NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT message_link_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_9F390228537A1329" FOREIGN KEY (message_id)
     REFERENCES message (id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
  CONSTRAINT fk_9f390228a76ed395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
     REFERENCES fos_user_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_9f390228e2904019 FOREIGN KEY (thread_id)
     REFERENCES message_thread (id) MATCH SIMPLE
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

The cascade delete constraints I added on `message_id` field don't work either from code or from pgadmin. When I delete a record from the `message` table, referenced records from the `message_link` table aren't deleted.

Everything works locally (vagrant) where I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 however staging is using 9.1.14. I don't understand how this can be linked to the PostgreSQL version?

Why isn't this cascade delete working?

Comment: Are you sure you created the table identically on the staging server?

Comment: This cannot be. Maybe you are referencing a different table `message` than you think. Are you familiar with schemas and the [`search_path`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tables are identical.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter no, I'm not aware of search_path but something strange happening there. When i delete message manually referenced records in message_link table still exist. After i added new records in message table from project, records in message_link (which i wanted to delete previously) disappear.

Comment: @Milos: This sounds like a matter of visibility. Have you reloaded your display after the `DELETE` was committed?

Comment: 1. initial state http://screencast.com/t/H7qM25Jwx
2. After i delete manually message with id  = 1456 http://cl.ly/image/290z3p3U031P  I reload message_link table 100 times

BUT 

when i made query over message_link table i don't get links with message_id = 1456 http://cl.ly/image/2U3I0v0s3V0k

Comment: can pgpool make this problem?

Comment: pgpool is certainly a piece to consider. You should describe your complete setup *in the question*. (Hit the [edit](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/74107/edit) button.)